# Whether function memcpy() causes symbol extension?

Tags: c, memcpy

I am a beginner and doing a quiz but I found the following code produced a different effect than I expected.

```
char *p=(char*)malloc(4);
memset(p,0,4);  
memcpy(p,&x,1);
printf("%x\n",*p);  //0xffffffef
```

I thought it was going to be 0xef but it's not. Is it the memcpy function that causes symbol extension? I wrote the following code, but the results defy my guess...

```
int x=0x89ABCDEF;
int y=0;
memcpy(&y,&x,1);
printf("%x\n",y);   //0x000000ef
```

Comment: There is no `x` defined in first snippet.

Comment: Do you mean "sign extension"?

Comment: If it's sign extension you're worried about, either change `char *p` to `unsigned char *p`, or use `%hhx` with printf (or both).

Comment: This is a function of the *default argument promotions*.

Comment: Most of this code is red herring. Compare `printf("%x\n", 0xef)` and `printf("%x\n", '\xef')` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Tj9dW9aE).

Comment: `printf("%x\n",*p);` is undefined behavior, because `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, and you are sending a single byte.  Try a cast in there: `printf("%x\n", (unsigned)*p);`.  Turn all warnings on =]

Comment: @Jason Not quite.  Due to the *default argument promotions*, that byte is automatically upconverted to an `int`.  (And that's when the sign extension happens.)  The mismatch is signed int vs. unsigned int, not byte vs. int.

Comment: @SteveSummit Of course.  I am silly.  That actually leads to the answer i see =]

Answer (score 1):

For the first code snippet you left out the definition of `x`, but it looks like it was what you had in the second code snippet: `int x=0x89ABCDEF;`. In the first code snippet, your `printf()` is fetching *one byte* at `*p`, which the least significant byte of `x` that you copied, `0xef`. That is then converted to an integer argument for `printf()`, which sign extends it to `0xffffffef`.

In the second code snippet you are copying the low byte of `x`, which is `0xef`, replacing the low byte of `y`. That makes `y` equal to `0x000000ef`.

In both cases, your machine is storing integers in little-endian order, with the least significant byte first, at the lowest address. If you had done this on a different machine that stores its integers in big-endian order, you would have gotten a different result for the second code snippet, which would have printed `0x89000000`. This is why code like that is not portable.

Comment: The machine or implementation is little-endian _and_ makes plain `char` signed, which is implementation-dependent. In addition passing a signed int with negative value to a vararg expecting unsigned int isn't strictly required to work, but passing a nonnegative value is, and in practice (including here) a negative value also does some value not nasal demons.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the memcpy function that causes symbol extension?

The sign extension (not symbol extension) effectively occurs during the default argument promotion, highlighted in bold below.

Supposing this code:

```
char *p=(char*)malloc(4);
memset(p,0,4);  
memcpy(p,&x,1);
printf("%x\n",*p);  //0xffffffef
```

is preceded by `int x = 0x89ABCDEF;`, then what happens is:

- Your C implementation uses 32-bit `int`, so the value represented by `0x89ABCDEF`, 89ABCDEF<sub>16</sub> is too large for an `int`. (The largest `int` value is 7FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>.) The C standard says it is converted to `int` in an implementation-defined way (meaning the C implementation must document what it does.) Your C implementation probably adjusts it modulo 2<sup>32</sup> to a representable value (equivalent to taking the low 32 bits of the value), producing the value −1,985,229,329, which is represented in memory with the same bits as `unsigned` 89ABCDEF<sub>16</sub>.
- `memcpy(p,&x,1);` copies one byte from `x` to where `p` points. Your C implementation stores bytes of `int` objects in little-endian order, meaning the least significant byte is at a lower memory address. The least significant byte of −1,985,229,329 is EF<sub>16</sub>.
- In `printf("%x\n",*p);`, `*p` fetches the `char` that `p` points to. This `char` is represented by the byte EF<sub>16</sub>. Your C implementation uses a two’s complement signed `char`, so this byte is interpreted as an eight-bit two’s complement number. In eight-bit two’s complement, EF<sub>16</sub> represents −17.
- To pass the argument to `printf`, which does not have specific parameter types after the first argument, because it is declared as `printf(const char * restrict,...)`, the default argument promotions are applied. **The default argument promotions convert a `char` to an `int` (in all normal C implementations). So an `int` with the value −17 is passed to `printf`.**
- Your C implementation uses 32-bit two’s complement for `int`. In this format, −17 is represented as FFFFFFEF<sub>16</sub>.
- `%x` tells `printf` to expect an `unsigned int`. You passed an `int`, and the C standard does not define what happens when you do this. However, what commonly happens is that the bytes you passed for an `int`, FFFFFFEF<sub>16</sub> are used and are interpreted as an `unsigned int`.
- `printf` formats this reinterpreted `unsigned int` as “ffffffef” and prints it.

In this code:

```
int x=0x89ABCDEF;
int y=0;
memcpy(&y,&x,1);
printf("%x\n",y);
```

- `x` is initialized as above.
- `y` is initialized with zero bytes.
- `memcpy(&y,&x,1);` copies a single byte from `x` into `y`. Since your C implementation uses little-endian order, this copies the EF<sub>16</sub> byte, and the result is `y` contains 000000EF<sub>16</sub>.
- In `printf("%x\n",y);`, `y` fetches the `int` stored in `y`. The bytes 000000EF<sub>16</sub> represent the value EF<sub>16</sub> (239).
- The default argument promotions are applied but have no effect; an `int` remains an `int`. So the `int` value represented by  000000EF<sub>16</sub> is passed to `printf`.
- As above, `%x` tells `printf` to expect an `unsigned int`. You passed an `int`, and the C standard does not define what happens when you do this. However, what commonly happens is that the bytes you passed for an `int`, 000000EF<sub>16</sub> are used and are interpreted as an `unsigned int`.
- `printf` formats this reinterpreted `unsigned int` as “ef” and prints it.

Comment: At least with regard to two's complement, C23 will, thankfully, make two's complement representation part of the standard for integers.

Answer (score -1):

The output doesn't result from `memcpy()`.

There are two reason: complement (or signed bit) and automic type cast.

---

Do you know complement, inverse code and orignal code ?
Complement means that the highest bit will be used as "signed bit"(to distinguish between '+' and '-' ).

the complement of positive number is equal to its original code so we don't care about it.

```c
    char positive_1 = 0b10000001; //It is "-1"
    char negative_1 = 0b00000001; //It is "1"
    
    printf ("%x\n", positive_1); //output ffffff81
    printf ("%x\n", negative_1); //output 1
```

`positive_1` is negative, so it is a complement.
In original code, we add `0` to widen number.
For example: `0b00011` == `0b11`.

But in inverse code, we add `1` to widen number.
For example: `0b1110` == `0b10`.

Complement is equal to inverse code + 1.

---

Back to the above example,
`char positive_1 = 0b10000001;`

Because of automatic cast, it will be widen to `unsigned int` in `printf`.

So it will be widen to `0b1111111111.....10000001`.

`%x` print it as hex number.

`0b1111` is `f`（8,4,2,1）, which results in the prefix: `0xffff...`.

As for the suffix, `1000` is `0x8`, `0001` is `0x1`.

So it outputs `ffffff81`.

You can use `unsigned char` if you don't hope to be affected by signed bit:

```c
int x = 0x89ABCDEF;
unsigned *p = malloc (4);
memset (p, 0, 4);
memcpy (p, &x, 1);
printf ("%x\n", *p); //output ef
```

---

Another example bases on your code may help you to think more:

```c
int x = 0x89ABCD7F;
char *p = (char *) malloc (4);
memset (p, 0, 4);
memcpy (p, &x, 1);
printf ("%x\n", *p); //output: 7f
```

```c
int x = 0x89ABCD8F;
char *p = (char *) malloc (4);
memset (p, 0, 4);
memcpy (p, &x, 1);
printf ("%x\n", *p); //output: ffffff8f
```

Forgive me for my poor English， please.